# applying css to a form with div

Tags: html, css, forms

my form is

```
<div id="search">
    <form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="Gsitesearch(this)">
        <input name="q" type="hidden" />
        <input name="qfront" type="text" style="width: 80px" />
    </form>
</div>
```

in styles css i have put

```
#search {font: 12px  'Arial', sans-serif; color:#fff; text-align:left}
```

however the form is still not showing the white colour

Comment: There's probably another style overriding it. Can you post all of the CSS or link us to a live demo?

Comment: for background color for div use background-color in your css its working

Comment: for demo check here http://jsfiddle.net/PRBBx/

Comment: solved, slipped my mind you where totally right

Answer (score 3):

`INPUT` elements generally do not inherit color or font styles from the surrounding text by default. For example, in an area with blue text, the color of the `INPUT` value is still going to be the browser default (usually black). To override this, you need to target the `INPUT` specifically. In your case, try:

```
#search input { font: 12px 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#fff; }
```